# How do I make my ASP.NET page encode the value selected in a listbox as a parameter to an HTTP request URL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I have a listbox on an ASP.NET page:

```
<select id="Language" multiple size="5" name="Language" runat="server">
    <option value="English" selected>English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
</select>
```

and the form that contains that listbox has a "Submit" button

```
<asp:Button id="btnPost" runat="server" text="Submit"
    postbackurl="ProcessData.asmx"/>
```

I'd like the page to form a request to `ProcessData.asmx?Language=X` when `X` is selected in the listbox.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Your select simply have to be a part of form. As form submitted it submit all inside control values to action.

```
<form id="submit" action="ProcessData.asmx" runat="server">
<select id="Language" multiple size="5" name="Language" runat="server">
    <option value="English" selected>English</option>
    <option value="French">French</option>
    <option value="German">German</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" text="Submit form"/>
</form>
```

Submit button with do job for you :)

Comment: This appraoch won't set a query string parameter, however, I believe that in this case there is no need to send the language as a query string param at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the value on the target page using `Request.Form["Language"]`

Or set the OnClientClick attribute to 
`"javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions('btnPost', '', '', false, '', 'ProcessData.asmx?Language=' + GetSelectedLang();, false, false))"`

and add GetSelectedLang() javascript function your page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do the following:

1) Hook on the OnClientClick event of the submit button.
2) Cancel that event using return false.
3) In the OnClientClick event handler send manually a GET request to ProcessData.asmx using XmlHttpRequest and append the needed query string parameter.. I suggest that you use 3rd party JavaScript Ajax library to do that. Here is short example using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientClick() {
        var $ = jQuery;
        $.get(
            url = "ProcessData.asmx",
            data = { Language : $get('<%= Language.ClientID %>').value }
        );
    }


</script>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Postback" OnClientClick="clientClick(); return false"/>
```